# Difference Between Quota and Sales Count in Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

This is driving me nuts.

I have a table of sales information based on dates as followed.

```
Date       Price
1/1/12      5
2/1/12      5
12/1/12     5
```

Now i've used a pivot table firstly to group by week, then count the number of values for sales and tally up the Price as followed

```
Week               Quantity  Revenue
1/1/12 - 7/1/12       2         10
8/1/12 - 15/1/12      1         5
```

I have a 'quota' or desired quantity per week which is 3 and i'd like another column that subtracts 3 from the quantity to give me a difference like so.

```
Week               Quantity  Revenue  Difference
1/1/12 - 7/1/12       2         10        -1
8/1/12 - 15/1/12      1         5         -2
```

I've tried adding a formula to do this but firstly i can't access the quantity column because its not a field and i can't work out the formula to make a field to replace the quantity column. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can figure to do it is to change the source data and add Quota and Quantity columns to it.  The quota has to be calculated so that it adds up to the desired amount per week, in this case 3.

[image: pivot quota by weeek]

The formula for the quota calculation is:

```
=($F$2/7)/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$22,A2)
```

You can then make a calculated field, here shown as "Sum of Field 1":

[image]

This isn't a very manageable solution.  And if you have multiple products and/or different quotas it will get uglier fast!  But it's the best way I can see to do it with a pivot table.

Comment: Thanks! that actually works quite well. you said this is the best way with a pivot table is there a way to do it without a pivot table?

Comment: You could do it without a pivot table, but it would be a lot more maintenance, especially with the week grouping.  If this works well for you, then I'd definitely stick with it.